# Memory usage of C++ application on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks

I have an application that does some Monte Carlo simulation. For each run, a 12MB file is loaded into a `std::vector<MyData>`. The object which loads and stores the data is referenced by a `boost::shared_ptr` which is removed from the stack when the run finishes.

I see the memory usage of the application grow in Windows Task Manager to about 1GB (after 80-90 runs), but it then usually drops down to 50MB (and start growing for the next runs). So I wonder if this is a memory leak or just normal behavior. Should/Could I do anything to explicitly free the memory in the vector or something else?

Thanks for hints,

Philipp

Comment: I have no idea but maybe you should consider using another allocator and see what happens. Hoard is a good example. (http://prisms.cs.umass.edu/emery/hoard)

Comment: @the_drow - would you really replace the heap manager without fully understanding the memory usage profile?

Comment: @Steve: No, not really. But profiling with and without can give you an idea of what's going on exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your hints. It turned out that it actually WAS a memory leak caused a lacking virtual destructor of my AbstractSensorDataSource class which was storing the loaded data.

Comment: That was the only possible reason - problem with destructor of MyData :) There are no memory leaks in std::vector

Answer (score 0):

That actually sounds about right.

```
90 * 12 = 1080 MB = 1.0546875 GB
```

You should consider using another allocator or reducing the number of rounds.
If you would like to release the memory explicitly you should either use a regular pointer or call the `reset()` function of shared_ptr.
Use a profiler, as others have mentioned to see if another allocator actually has a positive impact on memory allocation.